# why Http Post working when send to ip but not when send to url?

Tags: java

I am using [org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) to get a line of info from my server.

When I use the IP address of the server (the below is an example only) I get the info as expected:

```
HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/api/fetchInfo")
```

However, when I use the URL the server is not getting a request and the client getting a runtime error: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found.

```
HttpPost("http://subdomain.domain.com/api/fetchInfo")
```

The URL includes a subdomain.

the server i am trying to reach is a website provider and i'm able to interact with the website through the domain, so the domain exists.

the client is in my local computer and the server is on amazon ec2.

How to make it work with the url?

My code:

```
    String responseString = "";
    try {

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntityBuilder.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        HttpEntity entity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://subdomain.domain.com/api/fetchInfo");

        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log(ex)
    }
    return responseString;
```

Comment: where your client and server are hosted? the mapping between IP and host name is done at the network level and not at the application level. So I guess it will be a network issue

Comment: You'll have to provide some more information in your post: is there a runtime error? If so, what is it? If not, what is the content of that HttpResponse? Also, have you verified the domain actually exists? E.g. what happens when your cURL the url copy-pasted from your code (not typed manually or copied from somewhere else, _force_ the text to be identical)?

Comment: @AdiOhana the client is in my local computer and the server is on amazon ec2.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans runtime error: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found.
 the server i am trying to reach is a website provider and i'm able to interact with the website through the domain, so the domain exists.

Comment: @AsafBenTulila no, _in your post_. Remember to read the [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) policy article, and then update your post post accordingly: all the details that are relevant to your question should go in there, not in comments sections (and not left off, of course)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the apache server then you need to configure the subdomain.conf file with the server name subdomain.domain.com and in the /etc/hosts file onto the machine you need to specify the mapping of subdomain.domain.com name with the ip 127.0.0.1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: the domain is provide from a 3-party thet i ask them to point at my server ip on amazon, and in my server in amazon i use node.